# Tag filter on close vote reviews includes incorrect articles

Tags: bug, review, tag-filters

I have a filter set on my close vote review list of `[vb6] [inno-setup]` which correctly filters the list of possible posts. Most of the time.

Occasionally however, I will get a post that seems to be incorrectly tagged with one of my filter tags.

[image: Close vote review screenshot]

When I open [the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22432636/588306), it does not have the tag highlighted, and according to the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22432636/revisions), never has.

This would seem to be a bug in StackOverflow itself.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Ok, so [it was an audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4355861#./4355861?&_suid=13950566208940047406757136274735), but nothing on that page mentions faking the tags. Why does it munge the tags creating confusion and possibly erroneous review results? I'd still consider this a bug, especially as a filter is applied. Maybe if it picked ones matching the filter?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Stijn dupe is better :)